# Does the 20.04 or 20.10 distro contain support for USB/Thunderbolt 4?

Tags: thunderbolt

Does the 20.04 or 20.10 distro contain support for **USB/Thunderbolt 4**?

Answer (score 2):

USB4 suppor is available since Linux Kernel 5.6.
at this moment I'm running 20.10 with kernel 5.8, so I think this should be supported.

This may also be an interesting article for you:
[Linux-5.10-USB4-Thunderbolt](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-5.10-USB4-Thunderbolt)

I hope this helps.

Kind Regards

Comment: Many thanks very helpful!

Comment: TB3 is definitely supported on the standard 20.10 distro.  Haven't tried USB4 yet.

For those new to Ubuntu from Windows and using Ubuntu 20.10 try the boltctl command.  Still working to see how to get the TB3 ports powered on by default...